# how to input null set inside a array with json to minizinc

Tags: minizinc

Thanks a lot .
I am trying on input data with json to minizinc .
In the mzn file , defined the array ：

```
array[1..14] of set of 1..100 : stationCalendarOffPeriod ;
```

and input data in json , but error coming .

case 1 : use "{}" for "set of 1..100"  , in json

```
{"stationCalendarOffPeriod":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}
```

**error :**
stationCalendarOffPeriod:0.31:
MiniZinc: JSON parsing error: invalid object

case 2 : use "[]" for "set of 1..100" , in json

```
{"stationCalendarOffPeriod":[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]}
```

**error :**
:0.0:
MiniZinc: type error: arrays cannot be elements of arrays

so how to define set in json to minizinc ?

Comment: Case 1 can actually work depending on what you are trying to do. 
You can also use an integer like `-1` as marker for empty sets.
You should provide more detail of your code for us to be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.7.6/en/spec.html#json-support), the JSON input of sets must be given as an object with a single key `"set"` with a value that lists the values.

So, for example, the empty set `{}` is given as `{"set": []}`, and the set `{3,5,7}` can be given as `{"set": [3,5,7]}`.

When you have many consecutive members, then you can use ranges in the list. For example, `1..5 union 7..12` can be given as `{"set": [[1,5],[7,12]]}`